# Arduino help blue tooth

Tags: java, eclipse, bluetooth, arduino

Okay so I am doing a project for my engineering class and i was just hoping to get a second opinion on if I am missing something or not.

My project will entail writing an alarm clock quiz android application in the eclipse IDE and from there we will communicate with a Bluetooth transceiver that is connected to an arduino. The arduino will then send a signal to a noise maker to make noise once it is sent a signal from the android application. In order to turn off the noise maker the user must take a quiz on the android application. Once enough questions have been answered correctly, the app will send a signal to the arduino though bluetooth which will turn off the noise maker.

I am not worried about the android application itself, however, I have never worked with arduino or Bluetooth.  From my understanding I can in fact do everything in Java could someone please tell me if i am wrong?

Any tips, advice, warnings, and/or words of encouragement are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

no everything, on the arduino you need to write in simil C++ language, but it is similar to java, at least for basic code like your :)